# Lua custom linked list for class creation practice fails to set node.next

Tags: class, lua, linked-list

So I've been trying to figure out how to mimic classes in lua. So I could start with some basic code that I already have written in other languages, I started with a linked list. I have what seems to be a working node class, but when i try to print out the list from my LList class, I cant seem to get it to print.

There seems to be a problem where after the first node is added to the list, either the second node that is added gets overwritten by the third, or it simply doesn't actually get added. This could be a problem with a while loop I'm using, but I have no idea why it would be an issue in this case.

Here is the Linked List "class"

```
LList = {}

LList.__index = LList



function LList.create()

    local list = {} -- our new object

    setmetatable(list,LList) -- make LList handle lookup

    list.count = 0 -- initialize our object

    list.head = nil

    return list

end



function LList:add(newNode)
    print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): newNode.data: "..newNode:getData().." LList.count: "..self.count)

    if(self.head) then
        local curr = self.head
        print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): self.head:toString(): "..self.head:toString())
        print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): curr:toString(): "..curr:toString())
        print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): newNode:toString: "..newNode:toString())

        while curr.nextNode do --this is the while loop in question
            print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): in while:"..curr:toString())
            curr = curr.nextNode

        end

        curr:setNext(newNode)
        print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): curr.nextNode:toString(): "..curr.nextNode:toString())

        self.count = self.count + 1
    else
        self.head = newNode

        self.count = 1
        print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): self.count" .. self.count .." self.head:getData(): ".. self.head:getData())

    end
    print("DEBUG PRINT: LList:add(): EXITING\n")

end

function LList:getLen()
    return self.count
end

function LList:toString()
print("Stubbed toString()")
if(head)then
    print(self:toStringHelper(head))
else
    print("emptyList")
    end
 end

    function LList:toStringHelper(currNode)

    if(currNode.nextNode)then
        return currNode:toString() .. toStringHelper(currNode.nextNode)
    else
        return currNode:toString()
    end
end
```

This here is the Node "class"

```
Node = {}

Node.__index = Node



function Node.create(newData)

    local tNode = {}

    setmetatable(tNode, Node)

    tNode.data = newData

    return tNode

end

function Node:getData()
    return self.data
end

function Node:getNext()
    return self.nextNode
end

function Node:setNext(newNode)
    self.nextNode = newNode
    print("DEBUG PRINT: Node:setNext(): self.nextNode:toString(): "..self.nextNode:toString())
end

function Node:hasNext()
    if self.nextNode then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function Node:toString()
    return tostring(self.data)
end
```

This is the tester code. Again, all code is in one file for ease of testing.

```
testerList = LList.create()
print(testerList:getLen())

tNode1=Node.create(5)
tNode2=Node.create(7)
tNode3=Node.create(2)

testerList:add(tNode1)
testerList:add(tNode2)
testerList:add(tNode3)

print(testerList:getLen())

print(testerList:toString())
```

I believe that my problem is either in the while loop implementation, or in the way I'm setting the Node.nextNode data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me after fixing some typos in your code:

In `LList:toString()` you need to replace the references to `head` with `self:head` and in `LList:toStringHelper(currNode)` you need to replace the references to `toStringHelper` with `self:toStringHelper`. After this the code prints out the correct list.